# Help with a simplification

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm trying to solve what I thought was a fairly simple integration problem where I need to find the volume of something, but I've gotten stuck.

I'm using the "disk/washer" method, and the integral I need to solve is this:

$$ \int_0^{\pi \over4} \pi\left(\left(2-\sin(x)\right)^2 - \left(2-\cos(x)\right)^2 \right)dx $$

I've checked with integral-calculator.com, and I'm getting the correct anti-derivative, but when I try to evaluate over $[0,{\pi\over 4}]$ I'm not getting the right answer.

On integral-calculator, they say the anti-derivative is:

$$-2\pi\left(\sin(2x)-4\left(\sin(x) + \cos(x)  \right)  \right)+C$$

Which is exactly what I got when I tried to solve this. From here, I did the usual substitution of $\pi \over 4$ etc... but the answer I'm getting is negative and obviously wrong.

On integral-calculator, they go from that anti-derivative, to this:

$$-\pi\left( {5\cdot2^{3\over2} -16 }\over\sqrt{2}  \right)$$

I'm at a loss here. This answer is correct, but I can't figure out how to get from the anti-derivative, to this "simplification", and integral-calculator doesn't have any elaboration on how they got there.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated as I would really like to understand what is going on here. Thanks.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First evaluate at $\pi/4$:
$$-2\pi (\sin(\pi /2)-4\sin(\pi/4)-4\cos(\pi/4))=2\pi(-1+4 \sqrt 2)$$
Then evaluate at $0$:
$$-2\pi (\sin(0)-4\sin(0)-4\cos(0))=8\pi$$
Then subtract:
$$2\pi (-1+4\sqrt 2)-8\pi=2\pi(-5+4\sqrt 2)=-\pi\bigg(\frac{5\cdot 2^{3/2}-16}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)$$